# WPF - MVVM Architecture (Visual Studio Solution and Projects)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, architecture

I'm working on a Window-App WPF project in MVVM pattern. At the moment, the app is a bit simple (can't really explain the nature of the product), but eventually it is expected to grow into a more complex app.

- The wpf winapp has a local database and also connects to a REST service.
- Development Time is not really the top concern; but maintainability, and testability.
- Will use an IOC container and DI
- Planning to do 1 ViewModel is to 1 View
- I don't want to use any WPF/MVVM frameworks, as this is my first time in WPF-MVVM app (just like first time coding in bare DOM javascript even if there's jquery).

I decided to use multiple projects, and here's what I came up so far:

1. **Product.Windows.Common** (Utils, Logging, Helpers, etc.)
2. **Product.Windows.Entities** (Database and REST entities)
3. **Product.Windows.Contracts** (All Interfaces will reside in this namespace/project)
4. **Product.Windows.Data** (for local Database)
5. **Product.Windows.ServiceClients** (for REST client)
6. **Product.Windows.App** (the main WPF project, contains the Views/XAML)
7. **Product.Windows.Models** (INPChanged)
8. **Product.Windows.ViewModels** (INPChanged and ICommands)
9. **Product.Windows.Tests** (Unit Tests)

I just want to ask:

1. Is this architecture a bit over-kill?
2. Do I need to create a **Product.Windows.Business** for the business logic? Or should I just put business logic in the ViewModels?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* As such, I have voted to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm currently working on an app with a similar structure. the project structure looks ok. in my project i did things a little differently though.

the Data and ServiceClients assemblies might represent your DAL. it's good these are separated in different assemblies. in the Data assembly you'll have the repositories and in the ServiceClients you'll have the service agents. The Entities and Contracts assemblies might represent your BL. Here, i think you could have used a single assembly. this assembly should be referenced by both DAL assemblies.

it's good that logging is implemented separately and if you have security this should also be implemented in Common. From what i've read recently, in a great book, Dependency Injection in .NET, utils & helpers are a result of poor/incomplete design. these classes usually contain static methods. but i don't think this is relevant to the discussion.

on my projects i usually implement the VMs in the same assembly as the views. this includes the RelayCommand (the ICommand implementation) and the ViewModelBase that implements INPC.

i've recently viewed a presentation by Robert Martin. from what i can remember he said that an application's architecture should scream what the application does. classes should not be grouped in projects or folders called (MVC or MVVM). this tells us nothing about what the app does. classes should be grouped by what they do, by the features they implement. i'm not at this phase yet. i'm still grouping things like you :).

i see that you only have a single test project. this might also be fine if you add directories in this project for all the assemblies you are planning to test. if you're not doing that it will be a little hard to find the tests for a particular assembly. you might want to add test projects for every assembly you plan to test.

Comment: Thanks @flo_badea for the ideas :)

p2 - great we agree on Data and ServiceClients.

p3 - yes, planning to put Security on Common. i might still go on 
with DI on utils and helpers (for possible multiple implementations in the future)

p4 - thanks for the thoughts on combining them. will think about it as well

p5 - great thoughts on that!

p6 - yup, planning to add folders per assembly inside the tests project.

Comment: on second thought, i think you're right. i'll switch to making utils/helpers as classes with static methods.

Comment: what i meant by utils is that these utils classes usually turn out to contain static methods. according to what i've read this is due to insufficient design. i'll give you as an example my curent project. so far it does not contain any utils classes. by the way, i haven't mentioned this, you should try to use DI if you feel comfortable with it. i'm doing this in my current project as well. this is my first project applying DI on everything and it seams to work great. the app is also highly testable.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your components as you want but i prefere the following structure:
- create 2 class libraries (dll) for each screen in your project (one of them has views + View Models for this screen and the other dll has the business logic for it) so you can use your view and viewmodel with another business logic and also you can change, update in every screen business/view separately and the update will work when you replace a dll.

- Use all of your components except:
  Product.Windows.ViewModels
  Product.Windows.Models

Comment: Practically, one will never recompile the _same_ view and _same_ view model in another application. Your view is tailored for your presentation mode and your view model is tailored for your application logic and data model. There is little room for sharing that between applications.

Comment: Ok, in my case i am sharing screens views among applications,but you can use one dll for each screen (view + viewmodel + business).

Comment: I have upwards of 25 different views. Do i really want 25 dlls?

Comment: @Gusdor yeah, doesn't seem right that the number of views dictate the number of DLL's

Comment: @WaelGamal - i've combined the Models and ViewModels into the main WPF app (much like how controllers are inside an ASP.NET MVC project)

Comment: @HwarangYokik- I don't prefer combining models & view models into the main WPF app. I am using Prism to build client applications (I have one WPF that runs for all of our applications using some configurations), so i prefer the Concept of Modules or Components or Blocks. Separating components into dlls is better than combining them into one dll / app. Have a look to Prism from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx

Comment: @Gusdor- You can have related Views combined together into one dll, but from the respective of reusability, testability and maintainability- it is better to seperate your work into separate components / dlls

Comment: @WaelGamal thanks 4 that. Wouldn't really want to explore Prism at this point, as this is my first wpf-mvvm project... but yeah, i'll have a look just to see some patterns. "Separating components into dlls is better than combining them into one dll / app" - agree with this to a certain extent.

Comment: @WaelGamal rubbish. In this context, seperate dlls are useful for enforcing a top-down 3 layer (presentation-application-foundation) structure and that is it. It certainly wont guarantee better maintainability and it certainly will slow your build times.

Comment: @Gusdor-rubbish. Have a look to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658094.aspx#Maintainability

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a bit of overkill, but I think only you can vouch for your own program. I think I would put **Contracts** inside **Common** and **Entities** (Depending on functionality). Also, I don't think you need to completely separate between the View and the ViewModel. It'll also ease the changing / debugging process if they are on the same project.
2. If your program is client side only you can have the BL in the ViewModel (At least if it's not TOO complicated to follow). If you have a main server and multiple client then you should not implement *ANY* logic (except cosmetics) in your ViewModel, and yes create a new project

Comment: thanks! #1 - great idea, i've merged models and viewmodels into the main WPF app (much like how controllers are inside an ASP.NET MVC project) #2 - this is client-side, so that's 1 vote for logic inside the ViewModel.